# How to color the column right after the line numbers and before the beginning of line?

Tags: vimrc, highlight, colorcolumn

Would be nice to color the single column just left of the beginning of the line, but I don't think it has a group name like `CursorLine`. Anyone have any ideas? Maybe some simple macro would do, using `colorcolumn`, but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps signcolumn? :h sign :h signcolumn

Comment: Are you talking about highlighting indentation?  [I made a plugin for that if that's what you're asking.](https://github.com/tweekmonster/local-indent.vim)

Comment: I was talking about the column left of position `0`, but right of the right-aligned line numbering when `set nu` is used. it is a whitespace column

Comment: Would `highlight LineNr termbg=gray` be enough?  That sets the highlight for the all the `set nu` columns.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now.  You want a visible margin between the line numbers and the text.  That's part of the `LineNr` highlight group and you can't color that single column independently.

Comment: I don't think there actually is anything there. It's just "the space between." So it should follow whatever color your background is. I think the closest you can get is the `Signcolumn` highlight group as @f41lurizer mentioned. (This of course only highlights the area to the *left* of the number.)

Comment: Absolutely no way then? :( i swear I've seen this format in screenshots of other terminal-based editors; maybe it was emacs. Perhaps vim could communicate with the terminal directly to set a column, and infer the location of that column based on the number of lines in the file (e.g. it is farther along for files with 100 lines than 99 lines)... or maybe it could be done with a bash script